# Is it easier to have aliens of similar races on your planet?

Tags: stellaris

When conquering/integrating an alien race of the same species, are there any effects that are added/negated?

Example: 
I have a human empire, I conquer their single planet and start adding their pop and my pop to the same planets. Because they are both human/mammalian are any effects that would improve their happiness or help them integrate without rebellion?

In comparison conquering a planet of fungi and adding them in the same way, would there be any problems due to their separation in species.

Comment: I changed the title since you're actually asking about different races that are similar. I won't be offended if you want to roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are a different species. Mammalian, reptilian etc. just describes the species group. Whether you are human, catperson or fungus makes no difference, each is a different species and treated the same way.

So, it makes no difference in terms of integration.

Comment: That's a shame, I would of loved to unit the human race across the galaxy.